# Why does exception in DocData.LoadDocData does not prevent the view from opening?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx, vs-extensibility

I am struggling with this one.

I have a Visual Studio package that registers a custom editor factory to create a custom doc data and custom doc view.

In the DocData, in the LoadDocData method, when I create the document, if the file being opened is corrupt a InvalidOperationException is raised.

The problem here is that I don't want the corresponding view to be opened but Visual Studio shows an error message but it still opens the view.

What is wrong here?

```
protected override int LoadDocData(string fileName, bool isReload)
{
    // Clear errors

    this.DocumentData.ClearErrorListItems();

    // Catch errors

    try
    {
        base.LoadDocData(fileName, isReload); // InvalidOperationException raised here
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (this.DocumentData.ErrorListProvider != null)
        {
            this.DocumentData.ErrorListProvider.ShowErrorOnIdle();
        }

        throw;
    }

    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please provide a complete demo Via OneDrive. We’ll reproduce your issue on our side.

Comment: I have found the issue. The problem was that in DocData.LoadDocData there is a loop that closes the frames for the doc views that is typed to ModelingDocView but my view was not a subclass of ModelingDocView.

Comment: You can post an answer and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that my custom doc view was not a subclass of ModelingDocView.

I found, by analyzing the source code in DocData.LoadDocData with ILSpy, that it only closes the views that derive from ModelingDocView.

```
public int LoadDocData(string fileName)
{
    this.codeMarkers.CodeMarker(8206);
    this.OnDocumentLoading(EventArgs.Empty);
    try
    {
        this.LoadDocData(fileName, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (CriticalException.IsCriticalException(ex))
        {
            throw;
        }
        this.HandleLoadDocDataException(fileName, ex, false);
        foreach (ModelingDocView current in new List<ModelingDocView>(this.DocViews))
        {
            if (current != null)
            {
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(current.Frame.CloseFrame(65792u));
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    this.loaded = true;
    this.OnDocumentLoaded(EventArgs.Empty);
    this.codeMarkers.CodeMarker(8207);
    return 0;
}
```